# Programming with PayPal to transfer money without manually input account and password

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm currently developing a payment system using PayPal.

I'd like to use the adaptive payment method to pay money from my account to other accounts without logging in, entering password, confirming manually by myself, instead, I may store my account and password in a file, and during the payment, this file will be read and used as the certificate for my payment.

Is this possible to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a file & filling the login user name / password won't work in this case.

But with Adaptive Payments, you'll be able to make the payments from your account to another by implicit payment (when API caller is also the payment sender).

> Implicit approval payments are payments where the sender and the API caller are using the same account. Because PayPal draws the funds for the payment from your own account, there is no approval necessary, and as such there is no visible flow for implicit approval payments.

Technical wise, you would need to implement a `pay` API call with `sender` set to your own account, you may refer to the [API Ref](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) for details

Answer (score 0):

The payouts API may be what you want: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payouts